# Merge columns of data in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a situation where I have two different datasets from different time periods.  While many of the columns are the same, some are not.  These "different" columns are ancillary data which should be retained.

I want to combine these two datasets, leaving NA where the value does not exist.  Note that these two tables do not have any foreign keys, and *should not* be joined, just stacked together.

Example:

```
data.a <- structure(list(lat = c(50L, -30L, -33L), lon = c(-40L, -30L, 
-50L), mag = c(3.5, 1.1, 2.3)), .Names = c("lat", "lon", "mag"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

data.b <- structure(list(lat = c(44L, -30L, -33L), lon = c(-40L, -30L, 
-55L), elev = c(1050, 2.4, 2.3)), .Names = c("lat", "lon", "elev"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

data.a
lat lon mag
 50 -40 3.5
-30 -30 1.1
-33 -50 2.3

data.b
lat lon   elev
 44 -40 1050.0
-30 -30    2.4
-33 -55    2.3
```

Expected result:

```
lat lon mag   elev
 50 -40 3.5     NA
-30 -30 1.1     NA
-33 -50 2.3     NA
 44 -40  NA 1050.0
-30 -30  NA    2.4
-33 -55  NA    2.3
```

What is the best way to achieve this result?  I see plenty of utilities to perform joins, but I am unsure how to do this operation.

Comment: just curious as to why you don't want common lon/lat data combined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

or with the more modern `dplyr`:

```
dplyr::bind_rows(data.a, data.b)

## Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
## 
##     lat   lon   mag   elev
##   (int) (int) (dbl)  (dbl)
## 1    50   -40   3.5     NA
## 2   -30   -30   1.1     NA
## 3   -33   -50   2.3     NA
## 4    44   -40    NA 1050.0
## 5   -30   -30    NA    2.4
## 6   -33   -55    NA    2.3
```

or `data.table`:

```
data.table::rbindlist(list(data.a, data.b), fill=TRUE)

##    lat lon mag   elev
## 1:  50 -40 3.5     NA
## 2: -30 -30 1.1     NA
## 3: -33 -50 2.3     NA
## 4:  44 -40  NA 1050.0
## 5: -30 -30  NA    2.4
## 6: -33 -55  NA    2.3
```

or `gtools`:

```
gtools::smartbind(data.a, data.b)

##     lat lon mag   elev
## 1:1  50 -40 3.5     NA
## 1:2 -30 -30 1.1     NA
## 1:3 -33 -50 2.3     NA
## 2:1  44 -40  NA 1050.0
## 2:2 -30 -30  NA    2.4
## 2:3 -33 -55  NA    2.3
```

or, if you don't want to use any packages:

```
rbind_fill <- function(...) {
  dfs <- list(...)
  cols <- Reduce(union, lapply(dfs, colnames))
  do.call(rbind, lapply(dfs, function(df) {
    df_cols <- setdiff(cols, colnames(df))
    df[,df_cols] <- NA
    df
  }))
}

rbind_fill(data.a, data.b)

##   lat lon mag   elev
## 1  50 -40 3.5     NA
## 2 -30 -30 1.1     NA
## 3 -33 -50 2.3     NA
## 4  44 -40  NA 1050.0
## 5 -30 -30  NA    2.4
## 6 -33 -55  NA    2.3
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(data.a, data.b)

  lat lon mag   elev
1  50 -40 3.5     NA
2 -30 -30 1.1     NA
3 -33 -50 2.3     NA
4  44 -40  NA 1050.0
5 -30 -30  NA    2.4
6 -33 -55  NA    2.3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(dplyr)
result <- bind_rows(data.a, data.b)

> result
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]

  lat lon mag   elev
1  50 -40 3.5     NA
2 -30 -30 1.1     NA
3 -33 -50 2.3     NA
4  44 -40  NA 1050.0
5 -30 -30  NA    2.4
6 -33 -55  NA    2.3
```